# Fake build unable to get desired Zip file structure

Tags: f#-fake, f#-fake-5

I want to create a zip file from a .net core web app publish, the app is currently published to an `_artifacts/MyApp` folder, but I don't seem to be able to create the desired zip file structure.

The published output is the standard for any aspnet core app

```
_artifacts/MyApp
_artifacts/MyApp/wwwroot
_artifacts/MyApp/<dlls, config and other output>
```

And I wat the root of `MyApp` to be the root of my zip file, that is something like

```
/wwwroot
/<dlls, config and other output>
```

I tried with the following but it includes the folders `_artifacts/MyApp` inside the zip and I don't know where I'm doing it wrong or if it's possible to do it with this tool

```ml
 [ !! "_artifacts/MyApp/*"
        |> Zip.filesAsSpecs "_artifacts/MyApp"
        |> Zip.moveToFolder ""
    ]
    |> Seq.concat
    |> Zip.zipSpec "Deploy.zip"
```

As far as I understand the docs, the key parameter is the `workingDir` on `Zip.filesAsSpecs` on https://fake.build/apidocs/v5/fake-io-zip.html

Comment: Have you tried using [Zip.zip](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/Fake.IO.Zip/Zip.fs#L99-99), like `Zip.zip deployDir "Deploy.zip" !!(deployDir + @"\**\**")`?

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for, very much apprieciated

Comment: Awesome, added that as an answer then :)

Comment: While this solves my problem right now, it ocurred to me that at some point I might need to create a zip file from multiple sources and the `zipSpec` function does that, but I couldn't do it,do you know what was I doing wrong?, do you know how could this be done with `zipSpec`?

Comment: I have not used that function myself, yet try to look at the [examples](https://github.com/search?l=F%23&q=Zip.zipSpec&type=Code). Although your code looks very similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose you can use [Zip.zip](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/Fake.IO.Zip/Zip.fs#L99-99) function in the same module:
`Zip.zip workingDir fileName files`.

In this case it would be something like
`Zip.zip deployDir "Deploy.zip" !!(deployDir + @"\**\**")`.